Cloning full content of a pic24fj128gc010 chip (Flash + RAM)
I have some hardware that uses a PIC24fj128gc010 microcontroller. This microcontroller lives on a pluggable board that is plugged in on a main board. This detachable board has the microcontroller with crystall and a small battery attached to the Vbat-pin of the PIC.
I have a second device that doesn't work anymore. The battery of this unit has fully drained. Plugging in the pluggable board from the working unit makes this unit work again. Attaching a new battery to the original pluggable board however doesn't.
So my goal is to transfer the RAM content of the working unit to broken unit. Assuming the state of RAM is the cullprit.
I have a MPlab pickit and can read the flash content of the chip, however I don't know how to read the RAM content (and write it). I am not sure if this is possible with MPlab, but maybe it can be done using Jtag?
Does anyone know how to fully clone this PIC-chip (flash + RAM)?
